# GridView with base adapter not responding to the first click on the first item in the GridView until i scroll

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter, android-viewholder

Am using a base adapter that create the child views for the grid and the holder view has more than one clickable control each perform an action.

here is the getView() method code

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_item_to_download, parent, false);
            convertView.setFocusable(true);
            convertView.setClickable(true);

            holderGridView = new BooksViewHolder();

            holderGridView.BookImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookBackground);
            holderGridView.BookName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookName);
            holderGridView.BookItemWraper = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_item_wraper);
            holderGridView.BookDownload=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.download);
            holderGridView.BookProgress=(CircularProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.demo_mpc);

            Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Isra-Thin.ttf");
            holderGridView.BookName.setTypeface(custom_font);
            convertView.setTag(holderGridView);
        } else {
            holderGridView = (BooksViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holderGridView.BookItemWraper.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams((int) Math.round(ScreenWidth / 2.1), (int) Math.round(ScreenHeight / 2.5)));
        holderGridView.BookImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.book_background));
        holderGridView.BookName.setText(bookCovers.get(position).getBookTitle());

        ImageView image = holderGridView.BookImage;

        //DisplayImage function from ImageLoader Class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(bookCovers.get(position).getBookImageURL(), image);

            if(bookCovers.get(position).isDownloaded)
            {
                holderGridView.BookDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holderGridView.BookProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holderGridView.BookItemWraper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        for(int i=0;i<app.bis.size();++i)
                        {
                            if(app.bis.get(i).identifier.equals(bookCovers.get(position).getBookID()+""))
                            {
                                openBookViewer(app.bis.get(i));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else if(bookCovers.get(position).isDownloading)
            {
                holderGridView.BookDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holderGridView.BookProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holderGridView.BookProgress.setProgress(bookCovers.get(position).downloadProgress);
                holderGridView.BookItemWraper.setOnClickListener(null);
            }
            else {
                holderGridView.BookDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holderGridView.BookProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                holderGridView.BookItemWraper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent openDetails = new Intent(getActivity(), WaitingBookDetails_Activity.class);
                        openDetails.putExtra(Constants.BOOK_COVER, Parcels.wrap(bookCovers.get(position)));
                        startActivity(openDetails);
                    }
                });

                holderGridView.BookDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        new downloadEPUB_Task(bookCovers.get(position), position).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                    }
                });
            }

        return  convertView;
    }
```

when the GridView first initialize if i click on first item on any control in the holder view it wont respond until i scroll the GridView slightly, Note: only the first click on the first item when initially the app opens than the rest of the clicks are fine and am using LazyLoading to load images to the ImageView in the holder view and the scrolling performance is great even on slow devices so its not a memory thing i guess.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, I am having the same problem.  All the onclicks work fine except on item 0

Comment: @jameson2012 not really, i forgot what i did but i think i removed the whole code and wrote it in another way

Comment: weirdly i fixed it last night, though i'm not sure i 100% understand why.  I basically said if(convertView != null)setOnClickListener.  What I *think* is happening is that when the view loads position 0 it draws and redraws it, possibly to work out sizing/spacing etc so it overwrites the original onclick which by the time it's ready causes the onclick event to be linked to a view which doesn't exit any longer, but a large part of my logical mind can't make sense of that!

Comment: @jameson2012 yeah i suggest that you use RecyclerView and follow the best practices because these errors can give headache for days.

Answer (score 0):

remove below line from getView() method and try it;

```
convertView.setFocusable(true);
convertView.setClickable(true);
```

add  the below  click listner outside  else part of your code and try it,

```
holderGridView.BookItemWraper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent openDetails = new Intent(getActivity(), WaitingBookDetails_Activity.class);
                    openDetails.putExtra(Constants.BOOK_COVER, Parcels.wrap(bookCovers.get(position)));
                    startActivity(openDetails);
                }
            });

            holderGridView.BookDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new downloadEPUB_Task(bookCovers.get(position), position).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                }
            });
```

Comment: it didn't work and i edited now my question because i discovered that only first item in the grid does this behavior, feel free to edit your answer if you now it

Comment: it dint work and as u see holderGridView.BookItemWraper have different onClickListener according to the state of the book so i cannot remove it from the else although i tried it and didn't work.  Thanks anyway

Comment: there is no need to add the click listener in each if-else part. You can check the status in onClick method of particular component and perform your operation depends on status.

Comment: i agree but still not the solution and it only happens to the first item of the grid and only at the first click, so my doubt is some mixing is happening on the initialization of the GridView and hoping that somebody who had this problem and solve it to see my question